# How I can extend my form login to Google Sign in (OAuth2) in Spring Boot, JPA, Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, google-signin

I have an app which already running in Spring Boot with Spring Security conventional login using user name and Password. The table looks like (id, username, password, enable). And some resources are linked with login user id, for example, a book entity( which is mapped with user id).

Now I need to implement sign in with google option. Here My question is can we have them (Normal Login + Google Sign in) both in this scenario without changing the core app, apart from security-related things.

My Idea is if someone chooses google sign in, after google authentication I will create the user to my user table ( in this case what can be in the password field, do I need to add another flag column?) and log in with this user. Means an Extra layer to match normal login.

My question is how I can achieve that. I have tried many blogs but did not understand much. Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and I used the pac4j library. It has many implementations [pac4j.org](https://www.pac4j.org/implementations.html)

Comment: Let me check, Thanks for your help.